# Cursive IDE: what project files should be ignored?

Tags: version-control, ignore, cursive

For a Clojure project with Cursive IDE, what project files should be ignored by version control? Is there an example `.gitignore` for such projects?

Answer (score 1):

The only ones I can see are:

```
*.iml
.idea
```

Put these in your global ignore file: `~/.gitignore`  on linux/mac

Comment: These are also the only two that I always add to my `.gitignore` for intelliJ projects.

Comment: Im not sure all of .idea/ should be ignored - you may want to share part of the configuration e.g indentation settings.